# Issue with getting a form submit to a .java page in a servlet

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Hey guys I'm working on a Apache Tomcat v7.0 servlet where the user enters in some values, gets sent to a page to preview then hits submit.  The issue is, once they hit submit I get a 404 saying file non existing.

Set up of project -

WebContent folder has the welcome.js file which sends to roster.js file to preview - within the roster.js file you hit submit and that sends you to this link - `src/bandServ/BandListServ.java` this link is contained within the Java Resources folder, along with the WebContent folder.  The Java Resources folder contains my packages and that's where I want the data to be sent from the form on the roster.js file.

Code of roster.js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
   <%@ include file="/includes/header.html" 

   %>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Battle Of Bands</h1>

    <p>Here is our band roster:</p>


    <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band1:</td>
            <td><%= request.getParameter("Band1name")  %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band2:</td>
            <td><%= request.getParameter("Band2name") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band3:</td>
            <td><%= request.getParameter("Band3name") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band4:</td>
            <td><%= request.getParameter("Band4name") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


    </table>

    <p>Ready to Rock</p>

    <form action="src/bandServ/BandListServ.java" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<%@ include file="/includes/footer.jsp" %>
```

Comment: This is happening because , your java file location is not visible. You might want to see  whether you can access the file in your local host. Try : http://localhost:8080/src/bandServ/BandListServ.java and see if your java file gets loaded, if not then you have got to find out the correct path and then use it. I am assuming that your port no is 8080.

Comment: When I use http://localhost:8080/src/data/BandIO.java or http://localhost:8080/finalprojectfor_client/src/bandServ/BandListServ.java I get a 404 error - I found that path by right clicking the class for properties.

Comment: To be more certain, could you post your `web.xml` and `BandListServ.java` class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to invoke a Java class from a form directly. 
A class should be created as a Servlet extending the [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class. Then the [deployment descriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html) (/Project/WEB-INF/web.xml) has to be modified to include the servlet class details and a url mapped to it.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>BandListServ</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>bandServ.BandListServ</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>BandListServ</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/list-bands</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Modify the from in the JSP to call the URL pattern defined in the web.xml.

```
<form action="/list-bands" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a servlet mapping that translates URL requests to method calls.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configureservlet.html

A simpler approach is to use Java Server Pages, which translates the code and does the servlet mappings automatically for you.

[edit]

Adding a link to a tutorial on servlets:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: Also, you don't deploy a .java source file, you deploy the compiled .class file.

Comment: Tuto I guess I don't really understand how to send it over to the class file.

Comment: A simplified answer:

Server first determines which application should receive a HTTP request form the URL. 

Then the request is translated into a method call of the appropriate servlet class as defined in the web.xml file.

Detailed tutorial is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html


(Just a note: Requests might also be preprocessed by request filters and responses postprocessed by response filters.)

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
<form action="src/bandServ/BandListServ.java" method="post">
```

is worng i belive.

action= "      " should contain a uri, which is mapped to a logical servlet name in your web.xml which is intern mapped to fullt qualified class name of the servlet. Instead you cannot specify your servlet name in the action.

your web.xml should contain saomething like this

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>BandServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.band.BandServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>BandServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/getBands</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and in the form tag do this

```
<form action="getBands" method="post">
```